# Interaction between viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: and layoutSubviews:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a view with subviews that I manage by overriding `layoutSubviews`. This of course gets called to do the initial layout when the view is created. I call `setNeedsLayout` as needed to make changes to the layout due to state changes in the app. This all works.

To handle rotation, I'm overriding `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` to do a little work to prepare for rotation (nothing visible; just internal state), then just allowing `layoutSubviews` to be called as expected with the new size. That is working great.

As a result of a discussion here on a related topic, I'm working on moving the layout and animation of my subviews into a call to `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` which coordinates the animation of my subview frame changes with the rotation animation. So in `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` I'm figuring out all my new frames, then doing the call to `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` to animate the frame changes.

The problem is that before my animation appears to begin, `layoutSubviews` gets called three times. I have break-pointed my own calls to `setNeedsLayout` so I know it isn't me causing this. When `layoutSubviews` looks at its bounds rectangle, it is already set to the new (rotated) width and height. So by the time my frame-setting code gets invoked as part of the rotation transition, `layoutSubviews` has already positioned the views appropriately.

I can't remove `layoutSubviews` because I need it for the initial configuration of the view and for my various state changes that happen while the user interacts with the app. I could rename it `myLayoutSubviews` and call it explicitly as needed (in `viewDidLoad` and when making state changes) but that seems like bad form.

So the question is: how do I keep `layoutSubviews` from being called or how do I detect that it is being called as a result of rotation and do so in a way that feels "right"? Certainly there is a right way to do this; I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. For me I had to use a variable `initialLayout` which I set to `false` within the initializer. The first time `layoutSubviews` gets called I set `initialLayout` to `true`.

#### obj-c

```
@implementation CustomViewController {
  BOOL initialLayout;
}

init {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  if (self) {
    initialLayout = false;
  }
  return self; 
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

  if (initialLayout == false) {
    [self firstLayout];
  }
}

-(void)firstLayout {
  // All my layout code
  initialLayout = true;
}

 - (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:
(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
   [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
   // All my layout code
}
```

#### swift

```
class CustomViewController : UIViewController {
  var initialLayout: Bool

  init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
    initialLayout = false
  }
}

override viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

   if (initialLayout == false) {
     firstLayout()
   }
}

func firstLayout() {
  // All my layout code
  initialLayout = true
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    // All my layout code
}
```